# Onclick Javascript Alert, Then Redirect To A New Window

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have an onlick alert, then redirect to a new window

This is what I have so far

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="pop()">Renew Subscription</button>
</div>

<script>
function pop() {
alert("40% Discount has been applied");
window.location.href="http://LINKHERE.COM", '_blank';
}
</script>
```

Right now redirects in the same window but prompts a "leave site? Changes you made may not be saved."

Comment: Means some code has setup a onbeforeunload event, unregister it before hand if you dont want it to trigger

Comment: Inside pop function, add event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is working code**

Execute it  outside stackoverflow, its not working here  I don't know why?

```js
function pop() {
alert("40% Discount has been applied");
window.open("https://www.wikipedia.org/","_blank");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="pop()">Renew Subscription</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.open()`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="pop()">Renew Subscription</button>
    <script>
    function pop() {
    alert("40% Discount has been applied");
    var win = window.open("http://LINKHERE.COM", '_blank');
      win.focus();
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party libraries like [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) to easily achieve this.

```js
function pop() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Success!!',
    text: "40% Discount has been applied",
    type: 'success',
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    confirmButtonText: 'Great!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
      window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8"></script>

<button type="button" class="button" onclick="pop()">Renew Subscription</button>
```

Comment: He didn't mention about he is using jquery or not and why are you loading new library? Why don't you suggest `window.open` with `_blank` target

Comment: I thought he needs the redirection to happen after the user confirms. So, I suggested this method. I believe I understood the question wrongly.